# Visual Studio 2022: error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe ... " exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, cross-compiling, masm

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (ARM 64-bit) Version 17.3.0 Preview 6.0 to build a Win32 (Intel x86 32-bit) application. I get the following error:

1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(70,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Sg /Zi /Fo"Debug\byteasm.obj" /D"_DEBUG" /Fl"Debug\byteasm.lst" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaC:\Users\James\Documents\Dolphin\Core\DolphinVM\VMLib..\byteasm.asm" exited with code 1.

But when I open a command prompt I can successfully execute the following:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx86\x86\ml.exe" /c /nologo /Sg /Zi /Fo"Debug\byteasm.obj" /D"_DEBUG" /Fl"Debug\byteasm.lst" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaC:\Users\James\Documents\Dolphin\Core\DolphinVM\VMLib..\byteasm.asm
Assembling: C:\Users\James\Documents\Dolphin\Core\DolphinVM\VMLib..\byteasm.asm

Since I can execute the same thing (?) from the command line I don't understand why VisualStudio is reporting an error. Any advice? Once I've done the assembly manually, can I tell VisualStudio to skip it?

Comment: MSB3721 is MSVS's way of saying: I ran `ml.exe` and it returned an error code. You would want to increase the verbosity of the IDE build to see what actually upsets `ml.exe`. With luck that will immediately point you at the root cause. There are various possibilities for different behavior between IDE and standalone builds: The current `PATH` from which `ml.exe` is invoked may be different, various environment variables (e.g. `INCLUDE` and `LIB`) may differ, you have multiple versions of `ml.exe` installed and the wrong one is invoked, etc., etc.

Comment: Advice: figure out why the command the IDE runs isn't working, so you don't have to build manually.  For that, you should look at the earlier error messages that tell you what kind of error.  (And include them in your question as part of the [mcve], as well as linking the project you're building if it's open source, like the [Dolphin emulator](https://dolphin-emu.org/download/) for game consoles?)  If this is just a one-time thing and you planning to work on this code and rebuild repeatedly, in theory you could build everything manually, or possibly even convince VS that .obj is done.

Comment: Is it possible that when you added assembly (in build dependencies/build customizations of your project) that you selected MARMASM (arm assembler) instead of MASM (x86) assembly? I'm thinking a likely scenario is that you have Visual Studio project and are getting an error about the assembler not being appropriate for the project you are building.

Comment: When building in Visual Studio you should also get a list of the actual errors that caused ML to fail. Can you post the error message you got?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion from @njuffa to increase the verbosity of the build was helpful and showed the error that it could not find ml.exe. I believe this is a bug in Version 17.3.0 Preview 6.0 since it is able to find the C++ compiler for x86. My workaround was to add the x86 tools directory to the path (which would break attempts to build for any other environment). Thanks to all for the helpful responses and advice!