# I am having problems building my assembly code in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

I am new to assembly and I am trying to build my code. But when ever I try, I get this error that I don't understand:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   MSB3721 The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Main.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /TaMain.asm" exited with code 1.    TestProject D:\VS\vs\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets 70

This file is not even in my project, I think it is the compiler but I am not sure why it is giving this error. Here is my code:

```
.386
.model flat
.code
start PROC
    mov eax, 213
    add eax, 432

    ret
start endp
end start
```

I am using the VS masm and Local Windows Debuger. The version is 2022 comunity. If anyone knows the solution, or if I need to add more details please tell me.
Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: What are the actual errors it found in the assembly code?

Comment: When you do your build, are you configured for "x86"?  Or "x64"?  Because that code won't work at all for x64.  For x86, you'll need to change all the `start` to `_start` (something about how coff generates symbols).

Comment: The actual problem is in the error message before the part you quoted. Please [edit] your  
post to include the **complete, exact** error message.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I checked and I am using x86 and changing start to _start did nothing.

Comment: @KenWhite The think is, that is the only error I get, there are no previous errors.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that is the only error I am getting when I build.

Comment: You can try running this from a command prompt: Under the Start menu, look for the "Visual Studio 2022" folder. In there launch "x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022".  When the command prompt opens, change to the directory that contains Main.asm.  Then run the command from your post: `ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Main.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt /TaMain.asm` and see what that says.

Comment: I have managed to reproduce this problem where you only get that error and no other errors. That required me to force my system to not find ML.EXE in my path. Then I get Error MSB3721 as the only error and it aborts. Right mouse click the project name in the solution explorer on the left and near the bottom of the pop up menu select `Open in Terminal`. A terminal should open. Just type `ML.EXE` and hit enter. If it says it can't find it then you have a problem with your Visual Studio installation. You might want to try reinstalling VS or check your installation.

Comment: You didn't mention what version of Visual Studio. Is is VS 2022 Community? There was another person who I just remembered had issues and he found that a VS 2022 preview version had a problem not finding ML.EXE as well. That question was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73230274/visual-studio-2022-error-msb3721-the-command-ml-exe-exited-with-code-1